# HTMLUnit is unable to fire ajaxCall on onchangeEvent

Tags: java, htmlunit

There are two HtmlSelects on an external website.

The first one ("period") has got static attributes. But the second one ("date") is in disabled state and has no options when page is loaded.
The ("date") field gets enabled and data is populated when ("period") is selected.
This functionality does not work when executed via HTMLUnit.

Mentioned below is my code

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(PAGE_URL);
HtmlSelect select = (HtmlSelect) page.getElementById("period");
HtmlOption option = select.getOptionByText("Q1");
select.setSelectedAttribute(option, true);  select.fireEvent(Event.TYPE_CHANGE);
Thread.sleep(20000);
HtmlSelect select1 = (HtmlSelect) page.getElementById("date");
HtmlOption option1 = select1.getOptionByValue("2"); //EXCEPTION IN THIS LINE
select1.setSelectedAttribute(option1, true);
```

Below is the exception that is caught

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[option] attributeName=[value] attributeValue=[2]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSelect.getOptionByValue(HtmlSelect.java:437)
```

It seems like the ("date") field is not getting enabled and populated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Without more details it is really tricky to give some advice.

Please report:

- the version of HtmlUnit you are using
- the PAGE_URL you are using to give us the option to reproduce your case; if your page is private maybe you are using one of these webframeworks and there is a good chance to find a demo page to show your problem
- check the page code and make sure the trigger of the change event is really the select
- There is no need to trigger the change event, This is done by HtmlUnit alreade; replace select.setSelectedAttribute(option, true);  select.fireEvent(Event.TYPE_CHANGE); with option.setSelected(true);
- try to figure out if the ajax requests gets triggered by using a http proxy like Charles or by enabling HttpClient wire logging

Hope that helps, if you need more support provide a complete reproducible sample.

Regarding your version: version 2.13 is really outdated and of course we did many fixes for event handling/processing and also for the select control. Please use the latest version - this is the only version we can support because the development team is really small.

Comment: Please note, added information. This exception does not occur in Selenium-html-unit-driver jar.. The options are populated and the required one gets selected. But the requirement is to use the htmlunit jar

Comment: The trigger is an onchange event on that select statement